# MFMailComposeViewController Keeps Closing Automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is a really weird issue! I have a button on screen which when pressed launches the MFMailComposeViewController using the following code:

```
-(IBAction) openComposeEmailScreen:(id) sender {

    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

        MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposeViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailComposeViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [mailComposeViewController setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"johndoe@gmail.com"]];
        [mailComposeViewController setSubject:@"HelloWorld"];

        NSLog(@"%@",_pasteBoard.string);

        [mailComposeViewController setMessageBody:_pasteBoard.string isHTML:NO];

        [self presentViewController:mailComposeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

-(void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {

    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Also, my view controller uses the correct protocol:

```
ViewController ()<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

I am running this on the simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MFMailComposeViewController` isn't supported in the simulator.  You have to run on a device.

Comment: Actually, on second thought it is weird! Should'nt canSendEmail return false in this scenario since there is no account setup on the simulator. Or it returns true because iCloud is already logged in.